# Add avs_FastSimpleImport to magento store

Tags: magento-1.9, avs-fastsimpleimport

I am trying to install FastSimpleImport in a magento store to import new products into the store. I've put the files in the app/code/community and the app/etc/modules folders (that's how I downloaded it from GitHub). But after that, the documentation only says "The above code is designed to be included into your own module." So I have a couple of questions:

- Does this mean I have to create a new module in the app/code/local folder?
- I am not very experienced with Magento. I just created a custom module (in the app/code/local) that hooks into an event to send updates to a warehouse. Can I add the code for the import of new products to this module, or should I create a new one?
- When I created the other custom module, I could hook it into an event. But how does that work with FSI? Do I hook it up to a cronjob?

I know these are a lot of questions, and it's not even all of them. I have searched for tutorials or tips on how to use FastSimpleImport, but can't find any good examples on how to create the custom module. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I think I need to specify my questions. How do I use FastSimpleImport in a custom module after installing it, and what does the custom module look like? Does anyone have an example or know a tutorial I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only know the first question:
using AVS_FASTSIMPLEIMPORT or HO_IMPORT you must create a lightweight module. this is my example for an import with HO-nl/HO_Import

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <module1>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </module1>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <module1>
        <class>module1_Helper</class>
      </module1>
    </helpers>
    <ho_import>
        <events>
          <process_before helper="ho_import/import_product::prepareSomeData"/>
          <import_before helper="ho_import/import_product::callWifeIfItIsOk"/>
          <source_row_fieldmap_before helper="ho_import/import_product::checkIfValid"/>
          <source_row_fieldmap_after helper="ho_import/import_product::extractData"/>
          <source_fieldmap_after helper="ho_import/import_product::appendExtraData"/>
          <import_after helper="ho_import/import_product::reindexStuff"/>
          <process_after helper="ho_import/import_product::cleanupSomeData"/>
      </events>
        <ebay_electronics>
            <log_level>1</log_level>
            <entity_type>catalog_product</entity_type>
            <source model="ho_import/source_adapter_xml">
                <file>var/import/ebay_electronics.xml</file>
                <rootNode>objects</rootNode>
                <childNode>getsingleitem_us_electronics_ebay</childNode>
            </source>
            <import_options>
                <partial_indexing>1</partial_indexing>
                <continue_after_errors>1</continue_after_errors>
                <ignore_duplicates>1</ignore_duplicates>
                <archive_import_files>0</archive_import_files>
                <allow_rename_files>0</allow_rename_files>
                <error_limit>10000</error_limit>
            </import_options>
            <fieldmap>
                <ho_import_profile value="ebay_electronics" />
                <sku field="sku" required="1"/>
                <_attribute_set value="Default" />
                <_type value="simple" />
                <_store value="admin" />
                <_category field="_category" />
                <_product_websites helper="ho_import/import::getAllWebsites"><limit>1</limit></_product_websites>
                <cost field="cost" />
                <price field="price" />
                <location field="Location" />
                <country_of_manufacture field="country_of_manufacture" />
                <name field="name" />
                <short_description helper="ho_import/import::truncate">
                    <value field="short_description"/>
                    <length>150</length>
                    <etc>…</etc>
                </short_description>
                <description helper="ho_import/import::truncate">
                    <value field="description"/>
                    <length>400</length>
                    <etc>…</etc>
                </description>
                <manufacturer field="manufacturer" />
                <qty field="qty" />
                <weight helper="ho_import/import::getFieldDefault"><field>weight</field><default>1</default></weight>
                <status value="1" />
                <is_in_stock value="1" />
                <tax_class_id field="tax_class_id" />
                <visibility field="visibility" />
                <_media_attribute_id helper="ho_import/import_product::getMediaAttributeId"/>
                <_media_image helper="ho_import/import_product::getMediaImage"/>
                <_media_lable/>
                <image helper="ho_import/import::getMediaImage">
                    <imagefield field="image"/>
                    <limit>1</limit>
                    <filename use="sku"/> <!-- optional, when the server doesn't give back readable image names -->
                    <extension value="jpg"/> <!-- optional, when the URL doesn't end in a filename -->
                </image>
                <image_label use="name"/>
                <small_image helper="ho_import/import::getMediaImage">
                    <imagefield field="small_image"/>
                    <limit>1</limit>
                    <filename use="sku"/> <!-- optional, when the server doesn't give back readable image names -->
                    <extension value="jpg"/> <!-- optional, when the URL doesn't end in a filename -->
                </small_image>
                <small_image_label use="name"/>
                <thumbnail helper="ho_import/import::getMediaImage">
                    <imagefield field="thumbnail"/>
                    <limit>1</limit>
                    <filename use="sku"/> <!-- optional, when the server doesn't give back readable image names -->
                    <extension value="jpg"/> <!-- optional, when the URL doesn't end in a filename -->
                </thumbnail>
                <thumbnail_label use="name"/>
                <gallery/>
                <media_gallery />
            </fieldmap>
        </ebay_electronics>
      </ho_import>
  </global>
</config>
```

then I have an empty helper/data.php and it works ok.

Note: HO_Import works (extends) AVS_FASTSIMPLEIMPORT. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer s_h, I might try this later because I really wanted to try and make FastSimpleImport work.